# Problem with using cyrillic letters in mhchem's \ce{} command

Tags: cyrillic, mhchem

Entering Cyrillic letters into the `\ce{}` command results in the error:

> Package mhchem Error: Assertion failed: Unexpected input character.

This error is solved by putting the Cyrillic text in the `\text{}` command. However, if I write

```latex
$$
\ce{A + B -> Продукты}
$$
```

in the Chemistry StackExchange forum, this gives the result I want (without producing the error):

[image]

So, my question is, why does it work in MathJax and doesn't work on my desktop or overleaf? Is there a way I could change the config of mhchem or do something else to make it work on desktop?

Here's the full code, if needed.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\author{Azamat}
\date{January, 2023}
\title{Cyrillic letters do not work in \texttt{mhchem}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{equation*}
    \ce{A + B -> Products}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \ce{A + B -> Продукты}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

And the desired output is:

[image]

Comment: MathJax is not TeX, although they share (much of) the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MathJax is not LaTeX.

The `mhchem` package only “knows” some characters it expects to find in chemistry formulas. Even with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX (and suitable fonts supporting Cyrillic), the code breaks with

```
! Package mhchem Error: Assertion failed: Unexpected input character. In case
(mhchem)                you think this is a bug, please contact the package
(mhchem)                author.
```

Use `\text` (which should work also in MathJax).

On the other hand, `chemformula` with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX supports Cyrillic inside `\ch` (but `babel` defines `\ch` for the hyperbolic cosine).

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}

\usepackage{chemformula}

\NewCommandCopy{\CH}{\ch}
\let\ch\relax

\author{Azamat}
\date{January, 2023}
\title{Cyrillic letters do not work in \texttt{mhchem}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\CH{A + B -> Products}

\CH{A + B -> Продукты}

\end{document}
```

[image]